# "Redirect" shell to gnu screen

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-screen

I'm just wondering.
Very often I want to quit shell connection. For example when I ssh to remote linux and after while want to turn off computer. If there is process running I can't turn my computer off because it would kill the process in current shell.
Is there any way to wrap running shell into screen? Or any other solution for that problem? Like changing parent of the process.

I have found something like this: [Use GNU screen as login "shell"](https://superuser.com/questions/52297/use-gnu-screen-as-login-shell)
Maybe there exists other solution?

Edit: ohhh... This seems like a solution http://monkeypatch.me/blog/move-a-running-process-to-a-new-screen-shell.html

Comment: You can post the solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ohhh... This seems like a solution http://monkeypatch.me/blog/move-a-running-process-to-a-new-screen-shell.html