# How to make a terminal freeze if its idle fr 15 minutes

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

I want to make my terminal freeze, if it is not used for more than 15 minutes. I do have the option to edit the .ssh/sshd_config.

But I want a script instead of this..

Comment: Could you specify *freeze* a bit more? You want it to behave like a screensaver? Or logout/exit? And why not use the sshd_config?

Comment: @ahilsend: If a terminal is idle for 15 min, and after that if I try to access that terminal, it shouldn't be accessible unless you do something else like entering a password or entering a new key combination etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32351/is-there-a-way-to-lock-command-line) for possible solutions.

If you use `screen` you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> to manually lock your session. Your user password is required to unlock it again. For an automatic locking after 15 minutes (900 seconds) just specify `idle 900 lockscreen` in your `.screenrc`.

There is also `vlock` which doesn't require an already running screen session but has to be run manually.

Comment: Setting time in screenrc will be locking the entire system right. I just want to lock the terminal session.

Comment: No, it won't lock the entire system. Just your `screen` session(s).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its not just about the screen sessions. I want lock any of the terminal which is idle for more than 15 minutes.  Is there any options for that?

Comment: You could [automatically run screen when starting a new shell session](http://superuser.com/questions/52297/use-gnu-screen-as-login-shell).

Comment: The problem is that I'm ssh ing into a lot of remote servers. So, if I'm not using a session for a long time, I want to lock that terminal atomatically.

Comment: What prevents you from running screen on all of these remote servers, if installed?

Comment: The customer doesn't want to run this command in their servers..

Comment: Seriously, I don't understand the problem. You asked for a *script* but you don't want to run a *command*? I already gave you a link on how to automate this solution, your customer won't even notice it if set up properly.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear replies I have given. The automated solution is for running the screen right?? I want a automated solution to lock the terminal.

Comment: I want to automate ssh timeout without using the sshd_config file.

Comment: This is an automated solution for locking the terminal. Just in case you missed it, `screen` is a separate program and does not refer to your X session. And you don'thave to edit your sshd config for using it but instead some other files.

Comment: I added  **idle 300 lockscreen** in **.screenrc** file. Then added `# if $STY is not set...
if [ -z "$STY" ]; then
    exec screen -ARR
fi
` Now the terminal asks for password after 5 minutes. But it was noted that at times, after giving password, the session again goes into password secure mode without reaching the 5 minutes time limit.

Comment: I think this will do.. Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: is there anyway to exit the screen after 900 seconds instead of lock it?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines in user's **.bashrc**

```
if [ -z "$STY" ]; then
    exec screen -ARR
fi
```

Edit the file **.screenrc**

```
idle 900 lockscreen
```

It will lock the screen which is idle for more than 15 minutes and if you try to access it again, you will have to enter the password.

Comment: Is there a way to exit the screen session instead of lock the screen since i dont have a password set so it traps the user.